# Visual Studio Code: Scroll speed too fast for selecting with mouse

Tags: select, scroll, visual-studio-code

I am using MS visual studio code editor Version 1.12.2 (1.12.2) on a MacBook pro on OSX Sierra.

When I want to select a bigger range with the mouse and I move the cursor with button down beyond the lower edge of my edit window, the editor starts to scroll in order to expand the selected range. That's what every editor should do, but Code does it so fast that I just can't make it to find the right position to end my selection (BTW MS Word has the same issue). Is there a way to slow down the scroll speed here?

Answer (score 33):

While not a solution to the scroll speed issue, there is a rather trivial workaround. Select part of the region you want selected, scroll down to the point the region to select ends and Shift-Click. Voila, whole region selected.

Comment: god bless you! this literally made my life so much easier @herrbischoff

Comment: I honestly cannot believe this is five years old and this still is the best answer.